# Why can't I use a static_cast from one Xalan class to its base class?

Tags: c++, xalan, static-cast

Why does the compiler (g++) complain about this line of code?

```
    XalanNode *docElement = static_cast<XalanNode*> (docBuilder_->getDocument()->getDocumentElement());
```

The error I get from the compiler is:

```
 error: invalid static_cast from type `amxalanc_1_6::XalanElement*' to type `amxalanc_1_6::XalanNode*'
```

Without the static_cast, the compiler prints:

```
error: cannot convert `amxalanc_1_6::XalanElement*' to `amxalanc_1_6::XalanNode*' in initialization
```

The XalanElement class is defined as:

```
class XALAN_DOM_EXPORT XalanElement : public XalanNode
```

The documentation also shows that XalanNode should derive from XalanElement, as you can see here - [XalanElement Class Reference](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/apiDocs/classXalanElement.html).

Within XalanDocument.hpp, the method signature of getDocumentElement() is:

```
virtual XalanElement* getDocumentElement() const = 0;
```

Comment: If `XalanElement` is derived from `XalanNode` and `getDocumentElement()` returns a pointer to a `XalanElement`, then you don't even need a cast and the compiler shouldn't error. Double-check the return type of `getDocumentElement`.

Comment: If `XalanElement` derives from `XalanNode`, then why not just make `docElement` a `XalanElement*` instead? I.e., given a simple workaround, is this question just academic?

Comment: I need to pass docElement_ into FormatterTreeWalker.traverseSubtree() which expects XalanNode*.  Again, the compiler complains if I pass in a pointer of type XalanNode*. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Again, if `XalanElement` derives from `XalanNode`, then you should be able to pass any `XalanElement*` into a function expecting a `XalanNode*` and it will be cast implicitly without any extra code, muchless errors. Clearly your assertion that `XalanElement` derives _publicly_ from `XalanNode` cannot be true given the compiler errors. Are you getting this from the source code or from the documentation?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. It should work ... but the fact is it ain't. I've now included a link to the documentation in the post. From the definition of XalanElement above (unless this is from the wrong header file, which is unlikely) you can see that it is defined as expected.

I'm hoping someone who has used Xalan-C++ has encountered the same problem.

Comment: Have you `#include`d the header that _defines_ `XalanElement`?

Comment: Charles Bailey has the most likely solution. You've included something that forward defines both `XalanElement` and `XalanNode`, but that isn't enough to get the cast to work, you need the full definition of them both.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesBailey, that was the problem. The compiler must have known about these classes, but they weren't implicitly included in the right order or some such, so I explicitly included them in my file. It's times like this I see why Java was invented.

Comment: Thanks also to @MichaelAnderson for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Xalan headers only use forward declarations for classes that they are not defining even if they are declaring functions that take or return pointers to these classes. (This is common and good practice.)

For your compiler to see the fact that `XalanElement` is derived from `XalanNode` you need to explicitly `#include` the header which defines `XalanElement`.

Comment: To give a specific example, in this case XalanDocument.hpp contains the forward reference `class XalanElement;`, but does not declare what it is derived from.